# mmap - SIGBUS error when dereferencing a pointer within range

Tags: c, linux, unix, mmap

I have a program that tries to read contents (8 bytes at `0x7ffff5ebda78`) from a mapped file (shared library) and it receives `SIGBUS` while reading.

The memory range of mapped file is:

```
7ffff5d81000-7ffff5f80000 r--s 00017000 fd:00 15209579 <file.so>
```

Reading from this address `0x7ffff5ebda78` causes `SIGBUS` error.

According to `mmap` documentation:

```
SIGBUS Attempted  access to a portion of the buffer that does not correspond to the file (for example, beyond the end of the file,
          including the case where another process has truncated the file).
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case where I`m accessing a buffer beyond the end of the file. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that given mapping belongs to your process when you are tried to read from it? If the whole mapping is accessible, then size of your file is near to 2Mb, is it true? BTW, you are programming for user-space in Linux (probably), so why "unix", "linux-kernel" and "kernel" tags?

Comment: Modified the tags as suggested. I didn't understand, yes, the size of the file is about 1.9M. the mapping was created using `MAP_SHARED` and `PROT_READ`

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of the code that opens the file and reads from it and causes this error?